# faithful module and tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and suppose $M$ a left $R-$module and  $N$ a rignt $R-$module.

Is there result: if $M$ is a faithful, then $N\otimes M =0$ implies $N=0$ ?

If the result is right how to prove, or need any other conditions?

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you aright, you are asking that if $M$ is a faithful $R$-module, does $N\otimes M=0$ imply $N=0$ for a general $N$-module.

There are simple counterexamples to this. Take $R=\Bbb Z$, and $M=\Bbb Q$.
If $N$ is a torsion $\Bbb Z$-module, then $N\otimes M=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Call a functor $F : C \to D$ between abelian categories

- **weakly faithful** if $F(c) = 0$ implies $c = 0$ where $c$ is an object.
- **faithful** if $F(f) = 0$ implies $f = 0$ where $f$ is a morphism.

> **Lemma:** If $F$ is faithful, then it is weakly faithful. The converse holds if $F$ is exact.

*Proof.* In the forward direction, an object is the zero object iff its identity morphism is a zero morphism.

Conversely, suppose $F$ is weakly faithful and exact, and let $f : c \to d$ be a morphism. $f$ has an image factorization $c \to \text{im}(f) \to d$ which is preserved by $F$ by exactness. If $F(f) = 0$ then $F(\text{im}(f)) = 0$ (since this is the image factorization of the zero morphism), so by weak faithfulness $\text{im}(f) = 0$, meaning $f = 0$. $\Box$

Hence if $M$ is a flat module, the functor $(-) \otimes M$ is weakly faithful iff it is faithful. If either of these conditions holds $M$ is said to be **faithfully flat**. Note that, somewhat confusingly, $M$ being faithful in the usual sense and also being flat does not imply that it is faithfully flat, as Lord Shark's example of $\mathbb{Q}$ shows. However, it is true that every faithfully flat module is faithful (and flat).